# Cache-Control Header & Browser Caching IIS7

Tags: iis-7, compression

I am using Google Page Speed on my website in IIS7 and I was wondering how to set

***Leverage browser caching*** - The following resources are missing a cache expiration 
**Leverage proxy caching** - Consider adding a "Cache-Control: public" header to the following resources.

I am using doDynamicCompression in my web.config and little confused how to set these ? Hoping for some help

Note: Reference being used http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpCompression

Answer (score 20):

Under system.webServer in web.config set for example

```
<caching>
            <profiles>
                <add extension=".png" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" location="Any" />
                <add extension=".jpg" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" location="Any" />
                <add extension=".gif" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" location="Any" />
            </profiles>
        </caching>
```

This can also be configured from IIS Manager under Output Caching but what the GUI doesn't do is set the 'location' attribute. Setting it to 'Any' will set Cache-Control:public.

You can read more about it [here](http://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/archive/2006/11/16/caching-in-iis7.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you already figured this out, but read up on setting content expiration in IIS [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770661(WS.10).aspx).

Note that this only applies to static content served by IIS. If you are looking to set caching headers for dynamic content (ASPX, PHP, ISAPI, whatever), you need to generate your own Expires and Cache-Control headers in your application. IIS will (quite correctly) not attempt to apply cache-control headers to dynamic pages that may include Set-Cookie headers or private data. ASP and ASP.net automatically set "Cache-Control: private" by default for all pages, but you can override that behavior on a per-response basis.